# SQLiteDatabase object

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Helper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper in that i have four method

```
onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)

onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)

addquestions()

addingeachquestions(Questions question)// I also have one class named as Questions
```

I declared a `SQLiteDatabase` object as "db" under my Helperclass 
but when i make `"db=sqLiteDatabase"` in my onCreate & onUpgrade method it works fine but when i don't make statement `"db=sqLiteDatabase"` in my `onCreate & onUpgrade` method then `logcat` windows says null pointer exception at line

```
"db.insert(Helperclass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);"
```

Here is my code

Helperclass.java

```
public class Helperclass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
SQLiteDatabase db;
Context context;
Helperclass helperclass;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATABASE1";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 52;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE1";
private static final String UID = "_ID";
private static final String QUESTION = "QUESTION";
private static final String OPT1 = "OPT1";
private static final String OPT2 = "OPT2";
private static final String OPT3 = "OPT3";
private static final String ANSWER = "ANSWER";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + QUESTION + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPT1 + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPT2 + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPT3 + " VARCHAR(255), " + ANSWER + " VARCHAR(255));";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;      


public Helperclass(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    Toast.makeText(context, "constructor called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    db = sqLiteDatabase;  //when i mentions this it works fine but when i don't it gives error. Why i have to mention this?         
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
     addquestions();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    db = sqLiteDatabase;  //when i mentions this it works fine but when i don't it gives error.
   sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void addquestions() {
    Questions q1 = new Questions("what is your hobby?", "singing", "dancing", "reading", "sining");
    this.addingeachquestions(q1);
    Questions q2 = new Questions("how are you?", "fine", "good", "sad", "good");
    this.addingeachquestions(q2);
    Questions q3 = new Questions("whats your name?", "sam", "jhon", "alice", "sam");
    this.addingeachquestions(q3);
    Toast.makeText(context, "addquestion method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void addingeachquestions(Questions question) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Helperclass.QUESTION, question.getQUESTION());
    values.put(Helperclass.OPT1, question.getOPTA());
    values.put(Helperclass.OPT2, question.getOPTB());
    values.put(Helperclass.OPT3, question.getOPTC());
    values.put(Helperclass.ANSWER, question.getANSWER());
    db.insert(Helperclass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Comment: because db is not initialized it will be null.

Answer (score 2):

No need to add `db = sqLiteDatabase;` line in `onCreate`. call `getWritableDatabase` method to initialize `db`object before using it.like before calling `insert` method in `addingeachquestions` method call `getWritableDatabase()`:

```
db=getWritableDatabase();
db.insert(Helperclass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Comment: this can't be done because if i add `getWritableDatabase` method in my `addingeachquestions()` method then

Comment: this can't be done because if i add `getWritableDatabase()` method in my `addingeachquestions()` method then.                                                        `getWritableDatabase()` calls the `onCreate()` method  and and the `onCreate()` method calls `addquestions()`  method which is  again calling    `addingeachquestions()` method this is recrusive call, a method that makes infinity loop that crush your app. it is giving the error of  database called recrusively

Answer (score 0):

You have to get object of Db in "addingeachquestions" method like this :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

or

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: this can't be done because if i add `getWritableDatabase()` method in my `addingeachquestions()` method then. `getWritableDatabase()` calls the `onCreate()` method and and the `onCreate()` method calls `addquestions()` method which is again calling `addingeachquestions()` method this is recrusive call, a method that makes infinity loop that crush your app. it is giving the error of database called recrusively

Comment: It will call onCreate()..have you checked it...i doubt it will do like as you said..

Comment: as per my knowledge the `getWritableDatabase()` calls `onCreate` method when ever it is used. correct me if i am wrong i am just a beginner. heard this from some tutorials. and even i check the way u said unless  not removing `addQuestion()` method from `onCreate()` its not working giving recrusive error

Answer (score 0):

Initialize db while calling your helper class:-

```
Helperclass helperClassObj = new Helperclass(context);
db = helperClassObj.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: i have done that allredy in my `MainActivity.java`-----------------------                                       `Helperclass helperclass=new Helperclass(this)`;                                         `SQLiteDatabase  sqLiteDatabase=helperclass.getWritableDatabase();`        `helperclass.close();

Comment: remove helperclass.close(); and then try again

Answer (score 0):

It is because instance of `SQLiteDatabase`, `db` is NULL.

You have absolutely no need to add `db = sqLiteDatabase;` in onCretae(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) and `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)` instead use the following code.

```
if (db ==null){ 
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 }
```

Comment: where should i use this code in which method ? or under class?                 and if i use this code in my `addingeachquestions(Questions question)` then `getWritableDatabase()` will call the onCreate() method and and the onCreate() method has `addquestions()` method which is again calling `addingeachquestions()` method this is recrusive call, a method that makes infinity loop that crush your app. it is giving the error of database called recrusively

Comment: Remove addquestions() from your onCreate and call it when you need to show it... then use if (db ==null){ db = this.getWritableDatabase();} addingeachquestions(Questions question)  method.

Comment: Create an instance of Helperclass in your activity or fragment and call public method addquestions() from the same.

Comment: `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
      sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);                                        //remove addQuestion();
    }`                                                                                                                                                                                                                               in MainActivity.java                                                                                        `helperclass.addquestions();`  //Helperclass helperclass;

Comment: its working when i am adding `db = sqLiteDatabase;` statement in my onCreate and onUpgrade method if i remove thoes statement error of database called recurly

Comment: if Mainactivty         Helperclass helperclass =new  Helperclass(Mainactivty.this); and then call  
helperclass.addquestions()